# how to get object based on key match

Tags: javascript, jquery

have problem in finding `object` from my `array` which is having all the `keys`

i want to get all objects which is matching my `array` of `key`

**Question:** how to get object based on key

**please help me thanks in advance!!!**

```js
var allUsers = ['ab','ac','dc'];

var allData = [

    {

       '_id':132323,
       'ab':{
           'name':'abonly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
    
    
     {

       '_id':9993,
       'dc':{
           'name':'dconly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
]


for(var i=0;i<allUsers.length;i++){
   var foundObject = allData.find(function(){
       return allData.allUsers[i];
   });
   
   // do other operation
   
   console.log(foundObject);
}
```

Comment: You're very close. You have to actually pass an argument into your callback in `find`. That argument represents a single element of your array.

Comment: that is what i don't know how to do

Comment: @EaB   If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how you can do that :- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a single element, use `find`, but you want all of them that fit this criteria, `filter` is what you should be using. If you'd like an explanation of the code, feel free to ask.

```js
var allUsers = ['ab','ac','dc'];
let item1 = {'_id':132323, 'ab':{'name':'abonly','age':34}}
let item2 = {'_id':9993,'dc':{'name':'dconly','age':34}}
var allData = [item1, item2]
let foundObject = allData.filter(object => {
 let objKeys = Object.keys(object)
 return objKeys.find(key => allUsers.includes(key))
})
   
console.log(foundObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to achieve this.

```js
var allUsers = ['ab','ac','dc'];

var allData = [

    {

       '_id':132323,
       'ab':{
           'name':'abonly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
    
    
     {

       '_id':9993,
       'dc':{
           'name':'dconly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
]

allUsers.map(function(el) {  
 allData.map(function(datael) { 
  if(datael.hasOwnProperty(el))  {
   console.log(datael[el]);
  }
 })  
})
```

Comment: Really like the usage of `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allUsers = ['ab','ac','dc'];

var allData = [

    {

       '_id':132323,
       'ab':{
           'name':'abonly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
    
    
     {

       '_id':9993,
       'dc':{
           'name':'dconly',
           'age':34
         },

    },
];

var matches = [];
var objects = [];

allData.forEach(function(v){
 if(allUsers.indexOf(Object.keys(v)[1]) != -1){
  matches.push(v);
    objects.push(v[Object.keys(v)[1]]);
 }
});

console.log(objects);
console.log(matches);
```

Here's the solution in plain JavaScript.

`objects` contains only objects
`matches` contains elements similar to array.